# Two POST requests on one HTML page

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a webpage that should allow a user to search through a database by inputting the item name, or collect all items of a particular category.

I'm imagining that this involves two POST requests, and although I have the function working for searching for an item name, I can't figure out how to create a second POST request in the same html page for the search by category function. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Here's my python function for searching. I haven't included any code for the "Search item by category" POST request yet though.

```
@app.route("/search/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        searchQuery = request.form
        query = searchQuery['query']
        results = SqlFunctions.searchName(mycursor, query)
        return render_template("search.html", results = results)

        # pseudo code for what the other POST request might look like
        # if request.method == 'POST':
        #     searchQuery = request.form
        #     query = searchQuery['query']
        #     results = SqlFunctions.searchCategory(mycursor, query)
        #     return render_template("search.html", results = results)

    return render_template("search.html", results = None)
```

Here's my HTML for the search page

```
{% extends "master.html"%}
{% block main %}
<form class="form" action="" method="POST">
  <div>
      <div class="banner">
        <h1>Find Your Expenses Easily</h1>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">
              <label for="fname">Search by item name<span>*</span></label>
                <input id="fname" type="text" name="query"/>
            </div>
            <span id="result"></span>
            <form>
              <button type="submit" id="calc" value="sName">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">
              <label for="fname">Search by item category<span>*</span></label>
              <br />
              <select name="query">
                <option selected value="" disabled selected></option>
                <option value="1" {% if category is defined and category =='Groceries' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Groceries</option>
                <option value="2" {% if category is defined and category =='Transportation' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Transportation</option>
                <option value="3" {% if category is defined and category =='Entertainment' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Entertainment</option>
                <option value="4" {% if category is defined and category =='Rent' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Rent</option>
                <option value="5" {% if category is defined and category =='Utilities' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Utilities</option>
                <option value="6" {% if category is defined and category =='Gifts' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Gifts</option>
                <option value="7" {% if category is defined and category =='Personal' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Personal</option>
                <option value="8" {% if category is defined and category =='Other' %} selected="selected" {%endif%}>Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <span id="result"></span>
            <form>
              <button type="submit" id="calc" value="sCategory">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  {% if results is not none %}
  <div>
    {% include "table.html" %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usualy use two forms and instead of doing:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

I do something like this (by the way I use WTForms):

```
if form1.validate_on_submit():
    # process the first form data
if form2.validate_on_submit():
    # process the second form data
```